# Where is my debug Output?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, methods

I am following a pluralsite tutorial without source code so I wrote

```
class Methods
{
    public void MethodDemo()
    {
        WriteAsBytes(32);
    }

    public void WriteAsBytes(int p)
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(p);
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            string message = String.Format("0x{0} ", b);
            Debug.Write(message);
            Console.Write("{0:X}", 0xffff);

            Console.WriteLine("Hey look here " + message);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(" space ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
}
```

And looked in the output and debug/output and I see nothing ?
This is my first time really working in C# so its more of a visual studio question or just a question of why the consoleWL are also blank?

My output is

```
The thread 0xb48 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2ffc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[12864] Formating.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12864] Formating.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

and I do not know where the console would be found in a WPF application.

Comment: if you build in `Release` mode there won't be any debug output. so check your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the code as part of a WPF application, that is why you are not seeing the output from 'Console.Write`.

To see the console output, you could either create a console window manually from the WPF application, but as you are just stating out, you may not want to do that. The easier option would be to start with a new project in Visual Studio and choose `Console Application`.

Comment: So correct, I just made a console project and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

There might be two possible cases that prevent any information written to the output window:

- The `Solution Configuration` is set to `Release` then everything marked with the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute, will not be compiled into the final executable. Check whether the configuration is set to `Debug`.

[image]

- `Program output` in the `Output window` is not checked. Check whether `Program output` is checked.

[image]